# How can we delete multiple file in C#?

Tags: c#

```
File.Delete(path);
```

I am using function above. 
I have multiple file.
How can i delete multiple file without calling `File.Delete()` function multiple time?

Comment: you can put them in a Directory and use `Directory.Delete()` to delete them.

Comment: can you explain, what bothers you with calling File.Delete?

Comment: Use threading!Create a method taking an array of files to be deleted and call that method using thread!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of deleting the entire directory, you have no choice but to call `File.Delete` multiple times. As per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx), the path argument is:

> The name of the file to be deleted. Wildcard characters are not supported

Answer (score 1):

There are no solutions that will allow you to delete multiple files using `File.Delete` with a single call. If your worried about performance you could put your code into a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

The files that you have multiples of must have different extensions, and in the path you have to specify which one you would like to delete, so if the files that are constantly in multiples are the same few extensions(.exe etc) then run a loop that gets the filename and adds on each extension to delete them.